# KML layer on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Hi I have 2 sets of KML files to be added to the google map.But I cant get these 2 sets to simultaneously exists on the map.Individually these sets are working fine.Can anybody guide me?
I set the KML files as below

```
kml19 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
kml19.setMap(map);
```

[Edited]

I tried to combine the two sets of the KML files and set it on the map.I find that after 16 KML files are set on the map, and then again we try to add one, the map does not dispaly any KML files.Is there any limitation on the no of KML files that we can add?

```
    kml11 = new  google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url1',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml12 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url2',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml13 = new  google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url3',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml14 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url4',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml15 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url5',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml16 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url6',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml17 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url7',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml18 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url8',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml19 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url9',preserveViewport: true,map: map});

    kml11.setMap(map);
    kml12.setMap(map);
    kml13.setMap(map);
    kml14.setMap(map);
    kml15.setMap(map);
    kml16.setMap(map);
    kml17.setMap(map);
    kml18.setMap(map);
    kml19.setMap(map);

    kml1    =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url10',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml2    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url11',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml3    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url12',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml4    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url13',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml5    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url14',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml51   =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url15',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml52   =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url16',preserveViewport: true,map: map});     
    /*kml6  =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url17',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml61   =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url18',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml7    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url19',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml71   = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url20',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml8    = new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url21',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml9    =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url22',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
    kml91   =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url23',preserveViewport: true,map: map});*/

    kml1.setMap(map);

    kml2.setMap(map);

    kml3.setMap(map);

    kml4.setMap(map);

    kml5.setMap(map);

    kml51.setMap(map);
    kml52.setMap(map);      
    /*kml6.setMap(map);
    kml61.setMap(map);
    kml7.setMap(map);
    kml71.setMap(map);
    kml8.setMap(map);
    kml9.setMap(map);
    kml91.setMap(map);*/
```

Comment: Don't you get an error with that code? what is kml11?

Comment: @ geocodezip I have edited my question.Sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one KmlLayer object for each URL:

```
var kml19 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url1',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
var kml11 =  new google.maps.KmlLayer({url:'url2',preserveViewport: true,map: map});
```

**UPDATE**
You are loading lots of KML files.  There is a limit to the number that can be loaded, described in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport)

> There is a limit on the number of KML Layers that can be displayed on a single Google Map. If you exceed this limit, 
>   none of your layers will display. The limit is based on the total length of all URLs passed to the KMLLayer class, 
>   and consequently will vary by application; on average, you should be able to load between 10 and 20 layers without 
>   hitting the limit.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.I will accept your answer.But is there any method that I can get this done?.Can  third party "geoxml3" help?

Comment: geoxml3 can display an unlimited number of KML files, limited only by the performance of your system (it renders the KML using native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects rather than tile based rendering).  Another option would be to make the URLs for the KML files shorter, that would allow you to display more of them using KmlLayer.

Comment: I m asking this just of curiosity.This lot of URL's was working perfectly in google maps V2 where I had loaded it using "GGeoXml".So, is this a limitation of google maps V3 and "google.maps.KmlLayer"?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that, I haven't used v2 in a really long time.  I would have thought the same limitation would apply, I suppose it is possible that v2 is implemented differently under the covers in a way that doesn't send all the URLs in one request.  Perhaps you can ask the Google Maps API developers.